# Increasing current with constant voltage

Tags: power, current, transformer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f027KS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I got a sine wave from an STM32 DAC.

Its voltage is 2.64 V. I wanted to amplify it. I used this schematic. Its gain is 4.3. I got 11.20V output of the op amp but the output current is 0.13 mA. I decided to drive a transformer with the output of op amp but the power is too low to do it.

Do you have an idea?

Some people say it is not possible to increase current with constant voltage but I don't know if that's true or not.

Comment: What current do you require? At what voltage and frequency? 'Some people say' - now that's just speculation. Let's try to stick with facts.

Comment: @Kartman I need 1 A at 11.20 V and 29 khz. My sine wave's frequency is 29khz.

Comment: Have a look at the TL084's datasheet. What does it say about maximum output current and minimum load?

Comment: for 1 A output current you will need two big transistors on the opamp output to build an additional class AB output stage. Or maybe there is an integrated class D stage available that can be run off an analog input voltage.

Comment: An audio amp of > 12W might do the trick although 29kHz is at the upper end of the audio range. What is the load you want to drive?

Comment: @Kartman I want to drive transformer with output of op amp and piezoelectric ceramics will be attached to output of transformer

Comment: This doesn't sound like it would be extremely sensitive to a little crossover distortion. So even a class B stage would do the trick, this literally just straps two transistors on the opamp output with no additional resistors. See the response from Matt here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/99487/class-b-amplifier-with-op-amp

Comment: Why an op-amp? A h-bridge would probably suffice as the load probably has a high Q.

Comment: @Kartman I get sine wave from stm32 mcu. Output voltage of it is 2.64 volt. I need  around 10-12 voltages. Thats why i used op amp to amplify.

Comment: Why do you need a sine wave? PWM and h-bridge will give you a sine wave at resonance and with better efficiency than an analog amplifier.

Comment: switching at 29 khz with suitable resonant circuit would allow neither amplitude control nor a lot of frequency control later on though. a non resonant filtered switched stage would probably need at least 200 khz switching frequency.. its more efficient but also much more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to increase drive output current is made with a fairly simple modification shown below: -

[image]

Resistor R is used to tie the BJT emitter to the negative rail and the output is taken directly from the emitter to drive a load connected to 0 volts. This class A amplifier will suffice in many cases but, depending on what the load actually is and what current is needed, more sophisticated drive circuits may be needed. The next step would be a class B amplifier: -

[image]

And, by the sounds of what load you are driving this might be sufficient. If you really were intent on keeping sinewave distortion to a minimum, you might choose the bias the two BJT bases and make a [class AB amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes#Class_AB).

[image]

Or, you may decide to go digital with a [class D amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes#Class_D): -

[image]

Comment: It looks schematically simple until you take the power management for 12 W output power into account. For a sine wave, this will waste ~30 W which might be already needing forced cooling. A class AB will be probably less hassle after all.

Comment: @tobalt please feel free to leave an answer that is appropriate for the question's detailed specification in comments (that I was not privy to at the time of writing this answer) AND note that I suggested that more sophisticated drive circuits were needed depending what the load turns out to be.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, I meant no offense and in fact upvoted since you included other power stage classes. I thought that there is no need for a separate answer when this one pretty much went already in the same direction.